# Yup. How to change error message text date

Tags: javascript, yup

How to change message text for date field:

> date must be a `date` type, but the final value was: `Invalid Date`

Now scheema looks like this:

```
let scheema= yup.object().shape({
        date: yup.date()
          .min(MIN_DATE, `Дата не может быть раньше ${MIN_DATE?.toLocaleDateString('ru')}`)
          .max(MAX_DATE, `Дата не может быть позже ${MAX_DATE?.toLocaleDateString('ru')}`)
          .required('Обязательное поле'),
        reason: yup.string().required('Обязательное поле'),
        comment: yup.string().max(4000, 'Превышено количество символов'),
    });
```

error is:

```
{
    "date": "date must be a `date` type, but the final value was: `Invalid Date`."
}
```

I need to change this text

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [`Schema.typeError`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematypeerrormessage-string-schema) as follows:

```
date: yup.date()
        .typeError('Expected a value of type ${type} but got: ${value}') // ex: Expected a value of type date but got: Invalid Date
        .min(MIN_DATE, `Дата не может быть раньше ${MIN_DATE?.toLocaleDateString('ru')}`)
        .max(MAX_DATE, `Дата не может быть позже ${MAX_DATE?.toLocaleDateString('ru')}`)
        .required('Обязательное поле'),
reason: yup.string().required('Обязательное поле'),
comment: yup.string().max(4000, 'Превышено количество символов'),
```